# How do I use 7-zip to backup files, but exclude some directories

Tags: command-line, backup, 7-zip

I would like to use 7-zip to backup a directory, but I would like it to exclude all directories named ".svn" (anywhere in the source tree). Does anybody know if this is possible and in that case how?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To exclude all .svn directories you need to add the `-xr!?svn\*` switch

For example the following will create a backup of the `C:\Project\To\Backup` directory excluding any folders that satisfy `?svn`:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip -y -xr!?svn\* Project.zip C:\Project\To\Backup\*
```

Comment: Thanks ManiacD, but I can't get this to work -xr!?svn\* gives me an error and if I try -xr!.svn\* it still won't exclude .svn

Comment: you need a backslash after ?svn for it to work that signifies to exclude everything underneath the .svn directory. -xr!?svn\\*

Comment: Don't worry I had heaps of problems initially getting it work as well. The 7-zip exclude switch -x (-xr recurse directory) with ! excludes filenames based on a wildcard search.  Without the backslash it is trying to exclude filenames that match ?svn* ie. asvn.log with the \\* at the end mean don't include anything underneath a directory matching ?svn

Comment: For details on how to use wildcards have a look at the help file shipped with 7-Zip. Helped me to fix a similar task a few days ago. 7-Zip uses wildcards a bit ... different ;)

Comment: I got it to work, strange that this answer currently is the only one that hasn't been upvoted. +1 and accepted. Thanks to to all who answered my question.

Comment: And if you stumbled here looking for general folder exclusion, note that the `?` is to match "period-svn" (`.svn`), so to to skip everything in folder `SkipMe` you would use `-xr!SkipMe\*`

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using 7-Zip to exclude the .svn (or potentially _svn) folders, I would recommend using the [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re10.html) command (use svn.exe from [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)) to export the working copy to a temporary folder:

```
svn export C:\Path\To\WC C:\Backup\Staging
```

Then use 7-Zip as follows:

```
7z.exe a "C:\Parth\To\Archive" "C:\Backup\Staging\*" -bd t7z -v2g -r
```

Then delete the staging folder.

This is what I do to backup my local working copies.

Comment: Thanks for the export tip. Available on TortoiseSVN menu too.

Answer (score 12):

You can exclude files with 7zip using a list of files or directories:

```
/path/to7Zip/7z a -bd f:/backup/backup_2009-08-23_daily.zip home \
          '-xr@\path\to\backup_daily_exclude.lst'
```

The exclude file looks like:

```
home\Photos\iPod*
home\dhltd\*
BlogMatrix\Sparks\db\*.archive
home\eclipse\*
.svn
```

The key is the -xr and in particular the "r" which indicates apply the exclude list recursively, to each level of the directory. You may want to use 2 exclude file lists one for absolute and one for recursive exclusions. The above is from a bash script that runs in cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

When I used

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -ttar -xr!?git\* aufs2-util.tar aufs2-util\*
```

it ended up adding the .git directory which I didn't want, changing it to

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -ttar -xr!?git\ aufs2-util.tar aufs2-util\*
```

got the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

When I used

```
7z a "D:\codebase\w.7z" "D:\codebase\Edison\otm\Webapp" -t7z -mx0 -xr!WEB-INF\*
```

the WEB-INF directory was not excluded. **Adding an asterisk before the dir name**

```
7z a "D:\codebase\w.7z" "D:\codebase\Edison\otm\Webapp" -t7z -mx0 -xr!*WEB-INF\*
```

Got the desired result.

Comment: asterisk part is the most important. This should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to backup a bunch of maven code directories and wanted to exclude any directory named "target":

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip -y -xr!*\target\* site.zip C:\code\site\
```

Relevant exclude parameter was `-xr!*\target\*`.