# Add to a 7-Zip archive: How to exclude certain file types/extensions?

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip

I want to archive a folder, but I want to exlude all media files.

How do I leave out *.avi and *.flac when archiving?

Comment: Asked and Answered here also....http://superuser.com/questions/28162/how-do-i-use-7-zip-to-backup-files-but-exclude-some-directories

Comment: this page has  lots of example and explanation of  every param  in each example. here:  https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples . for people who wanna deep dive

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Only possible solution is to use the command-line version (it doesn't work in the GUI [Add to Archive] dialog):

```
7z.exe a Archive.7z C:\Folder\* -r -x!*.avi -x!*.flac
```

The "Parameters" input box in the GUI can only be used for compression parameters and cannot be used with standard command line parameters.

Comment: Note that you might need to add r for recursive so it will be -xr!*.avi

Comment: If you use powershell make sure to wrap it quotes: "-x!*.config" I just lost half an hour over that!

Comment: Just as reference, this is my batch file to backup my C# projects in folder "C:\prj": "C:Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a prj.7z "C:\prj\*" -r -x!*.tmp -x!*.pdb -x!*.exe -x!*.dll pause

Comment: Interestingly enough, -r in my case was needed so that the extensions were actually excluded, but did recurse subdirectories with or without -r

Comment: @Clement in case of powerShell single quotes should be used. PS has ignored -x switch in double quotes like you said. `& $a7z a $archName $binpath $addfiles -m0=LZMA '-xr!*.config' '-xr!*.log'` works like a charm for me

Comment: @Level1Coder You're right! the GUI doesn't work. Despite the existence of a *parameters* text box in the GUI, it simply takes arguments to the `-m` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
7za -bt -mx9 a archive.7z d:\backups\*  -x!*.7z
```

and

```
7za -bt -mx9 a archive.7z d:\backups\*.*  -x!*.7z
```

Created different result. The one with `*.*` seem to work.

Comment: `*.*` will exclude filenames with no extension though...?

Comment: @micsthepick is correct. `*.*` means "must have extension, but the extension can be anything". See https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm