# 7Zip Zipping up directories

Tags: command-line, compression, archiving, 7-zip

I want to use 7 zip to compress and archive folders but I want it to exclude existing `.7z` files if they exist and not duplicate them with a `.7z.7z` ext. I found this but it duplicates the already zipped files

```
for /R "D:\Test\AAPS - 54" %%F in (*) 
do (
    C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a -mx9 "%%~dpnxF.7z" "%%F"
    if exist "%%~dpnxF.7z" del "%%F"
    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/28162/how-do-i-use-7-zip-to-backup-files-but-exclude-some-directories or http://superuser.com/questions/185135/7zip-add-to-archive-how-to-exclude-certain-file-types-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the batch file to this which seems to take care of most of my problems but I still would like a better way of doing it if anyone has any ideas

for /R "D:\Test\AAPS - 54\AAPS - 54 - Copy" %%F in (*) do (
C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a -x!*.7z -mx9 "%%~dpnxF.7z" "%%F"
if exist "%%~dpnF.7z" del "%%F.7z"
if exist "%%~dpnxF.7z" del "%%F")

Answer (score 0):

To avoid zipping pre-existing .7z files, use the dir command with the /ad switch in a FOR loop to only list directories and then pass each of those directories to the 7z.exe command you want to use.

For example, to zip each subdirectory of your "AAPS - 54 - Copy" folder without zipping any existing .7z files, do the following:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /s /b /ad "D:\Test\AAPS - 54\AAPS - 54 - Copy"') do (
     @if not exist "%%A.7z" "%PROGRAMFILES%\7-zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%A.7z" "%%A")
```

You can replace the "a -tz7" with whatever arguments you want to pass for compressing and archiving your folders.